# Execute MSSQL stored procedure in Mule CE 3.5 (Anypoint)

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, mule

I got an error message when I execute a MSSQL stored procedure in Mule CE 3.5 (anypoint IDE).

```
******************************************************************************** 
Message : Query type must me '[STORE_PROCEDURE_CALL]' but was 'DDL' (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException). Message payload is of type: String 
Code : MULE_ERROR--2 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Exception stack is: 
1. Query type must me '[STORE_PROCEDURE_CALL]' but was 'DDL' (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) 
org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.AbstractDbMessageProcessor:164 (null) 
2. Query type must me '[STORE_PROCEDURE_CALL]' but was 'DDL' (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException). Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException) 
org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/cur...)
```

Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.5.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd">

    <db:generic-config name="db2_Database_Configuration" url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1700;databaseName=db2;user=user;password=password;" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"/>
    <flow name="DB_MSSQLFlow2" doc:name="DB_MSSQLFlow2">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="DB_MSSQL/sp" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <db:stored-procedure config-ref="db2_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[EXEC GetAllJobs;]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:stored-procedure>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

However, the stored procedure, "GetAllJobs", can be executed on SQL Server Management Studio without problem.

Please Help ... What is the issue with stored procedures where as normal SQL select works fine with parameter?

thanks,

Kalin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this  `<db:parameterized-query>{ call GetAllJobs }</db:parameterized-query>` in your flow .. so your flow will be as follows:-

```
    <db:generic-config name="db2_Database_Configuration" url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1700;databaseName=db2;user=user;password=password;" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"/>
   <flow name="DB_MSSQLFlow2" doc:name="DB_MSSQLFlow2">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="DB_MSSQL/sp" doc:name="HTTP"/>
     <db:stored-procedure config-ref="db2_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
       <db:parameterized-query>{ call GetAllJobs }</db:parameterized-query>
     </db:stored-procedure>
  </flow>
```

Comment: thank Anirban!  <db:parameterized-query>{CALL GetAllJobs()}</db:parameterized-query> works!

Comment: BTW, the solution works on EE version. But still cannot work on CE version.